# Editing the Gnome Shortcut scripts

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I'm interested in editing the script associated with the "Switch to workspace" shortcut on gnome, the one that is assigned by default to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>arrows</kbd>.

I'm having some trouble in actually finding where the script for this specific behaviour is.

I've searched inside the `gnome-shell` github page and I was able to find `js/ui/workspace.js` `js/ui/workspacesView.js` `js/ui/workspaceThumbnail.js` and `js/ui/workspaceSwitcherPopup.js`

Do any of these contain what I'm looking for? I've looked through the code and I couldn't find anything specific. Does Ubuntu use a different version of gnome-shell made specifically for Ubuntu?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Edit: Title is possibly misleading, but I'm not entirely sure what to change it to.

Comment: I have the same question.